# How to publish to multiple web sites in visual studio in a batch

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webdeploy

How can I deploy multiple websites in a visual studio in a batch on single click; either using GUI or command line

Update: I think some people have misunderstood my question. Let me try again. I want to publish my website to multiple subdomains(nearly 50) one by one(by changing profile and clicking publish). It takes a lot of time. What I want to ask is that is there any way I could automate and speed up this process.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have same issue. did you get the solution?

Comment: I used msdeploy command line to do it. If you need any more help let me know.

Answer (score 4):

You can select multiple projects (websites) inside "Solution explorer" window and select "Publish selection" inside "Build" menu item.

[solution selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RL4A.png)

[build menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn492.png)

Comment: Any screen shots would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using TFS then you can setup specialized builds that can utilize deployment scripts to push to many sites. This article scratches the surface but will point you in the right direction. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191495.aspx

Comment: If you would like to do it outside of TFS then you will have a much easier time using powershell as you can import IIS modules to help. At that point you can iterate through a list of servers and do things like create/configure app pools and do generic file copies. Most importantly you can create variables in your config files and replace them through the scripts to target whatever machine you are hosting on. This is an older article but may help you get pointed in the right direction http://www.technologytoolbox.com/blog/jjameson/archive/2011/11/17/building-technologytoolbox-com-part-8.aspx

Comment: What about using `msbuild "project.sln" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=profile /p:Password=password /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true`

Comment: If you want to go that route then you would need to build a profile for every subdomain you would want to publish into. Valid way of doing things. May take a bit more setup time and might be a pain to manage the profiles if you need to make a change but it would work. The bigger thing you would need to consider though is if your production web.config would be valid on every subdomain without any further transformation.